# Libnfc is unable to set alternative usb interface

Tags: nfc, lib-nfc

I just got an ACR122U for reading/writing on NFC cards. However, libnfc doesn't open the device properly (via nfc-scan-device command)

I got the same problem with different machines (on Ubuntu 18.04). Usual errors concerning this piece of equipment are "Unable to claim USB". Several posts concerning this error can be found and after applying their solutions, I now have an issue on alternate usb setting:

```
$ sudo nfc-scan-device -v
nfc-scan-device uses libnfc 1.7.1
1 NFC device(s) found:
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to set alternate setting on USB interface (Connection timed out)
nfc_open failed for acr122_usb:003:005
```

Instead, I should get something similar to (from an online post):

```
$ sudo nfc-scan-device -v 
1 NFC device(s) found: - ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface:     
acr122_usb:003:011 
chip: PN532 v1.6 
initator mode modulations: ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps), FeliCa (424 kbps, 212 kbps), ISO/IEC 14443-4B (106 kbps), Innovision Jewel (106 kbps), D.E.P. (424 kbps, 212 kbps,106 kbps) 
target mode modulations: ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps), FeliCa (424 kbps, 212 kbps), D.E.P. (424 kbps, 212 kbps, 106 kbps)
```

Any idea where this could come from?

Comment: There is probably a PC/SC daemon running on your system. Either use the PC/SC driver for the ACR122U or stop the PC/SC daemon (or exclude the ACR122U for it).

Comment: Thanks. 
OK, I thought PC/SC was a low level API used by libnfc. My bad. However, stopping the deamon does not change the result, I tried:
`$ sudo service pcscd stop` right before the scan-device, but I got the same result, despite that some `ps -aux | grep pcscd` shows that the PC/SC isn't used anymore.

Comment: It also appears that you might be right: "the ACR122 device (and variant like touchatag) is the easiest product to buy but it also have the worst support: the device causes many problems with libnfc (and underlayer PC/SC)" (from nfc-tools.org webpage)